# Customize Top Navigation bar in sharepoint server 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, navigation, branding

I want to branding Top navigation bar with our custom CSS. in Top navigation bar html look like this :

```
 <div class="menu horizontal menu-horizontal">
   <ul class="root static">
    <li class="static selected"><a href="#"><span>Home</span></a>
        <ul class="static">
            <li class="static">
              <a href="#"><span>SubSite1</span></a>
            </li>   
        </ul>
     </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

but I want to look like this :

```
  <div class="menu horizontal menu-horizontal">
   <ul class="root static">
    <li class="static selected">
            <a href="#"><span>Home</span></a>
     </li>
    <li class="static">
       <a href="#"><span>SubSite1</span></a>
   </li>    
  </ul>
</div>
```

currently i have accomplished below output using jquery.

I want to know that is that any direct property available in `SharePoint:AspMenu`? so I would like to display below output using property.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm following, the only difference is that you have the two nodes as siblings (same level) versus parent/child.  You can do that through configuration without the need to customize the code or properties.

To configure the nav:

1. From the site, click Site Actions, select Site Settings
2. Under the Look and Feel group, click the Navigation link
3. Under the Navigation Editing and Sorting area, configure the navigation.

You can organize the nodes as desired, and add additional top level headings as desired.

Comment: but how can i do through configuration?can you please elaborate more?

Comment: Agree with Mike. Also you should have enough permission to do so.

Comment: I have trying as par your describing.i can sort ordering,hide and show node of navigation.but there is no effect on rendering HTML.